# Get length of an array in golang and store it in a const

Tags: go

I used the go playground to try this code:

```
package main

func main() {
    exp := []string{"HELLO"}

    const length = len(exp)
}
```

But it is throwing me this error:

> ./prog.go:6:8: const initializer len(exp) is not a constant

I can see that this is happening because the length of exp is changeable. How can i get the current length and store it in an integer constant?

I would think that I need the reflect module to do this, but I don't know how to do it. I tried using `reflect.ValueOf` but it did not work.

```
exp := []string{"HELLO"}
const length = len(reflect.ValueOf(exp).Interface().([]string))
```

Comment: Why not store the string itself in a constant?

Comment: what string are you referencing?

Comment: This: `"HELLO"`

Comment: i want the length of the array not the string inside

Comment: That's not an array, it's a slice.

Answer (score 6):

You can indeed get the current length, but that is by definition not a constant.  [Here is what the language specification has to say about this](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Length_and_capacity):

> The expression `len(s)` is [constant](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants) if `s` is a string constant. The expressions `len(s)` and `cap(s)` are constants if the type of `s` is an array or pointer to an array and the expression `s` does not contain [channel receives](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Receive_operator) or (non-constant) [function calls](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls); in this case `s` is not evaluated. Otherwise, invocations of `len` and `cap` are not constant and `s` is evaluated.

Since your invocation of `len` is as `len(exp)` we must test `exp` against the text above:

- Is it a string constant?  No; it is a slice.
- Is it an array?  No; it is a slice.
- Is it a pointer to an array?  No, it is a slice.

The three cases where `len` would produce a *constant* have been exhausted, so `len` must necessarily produce a *non-constant*.

If you would like `len` to produce a constant, you will have to apply it to a string constant, or an array, or a pointer to an array.  Arrays are similar in many ways to slices, so this *is* possible.  For instance, in your example, simply replacing:

```
exp := []string{"HELLO"}
```

with:

```
exp := [1]string{"HELLO"}
```

suffices.  Should you wish the compiler to count the initializers, using `...` suffices:

```
exp := [...]string{"HELLO"}
```

See [example on Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/fTELSp_qApE).  Note that because `exp` is now an array, not a slice, some operations cannot be performed on/with `exp`.